# How to Reuse Values in Dart Class Initializer in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and Dart, so go easy on me!

I have a custom set of colors that I'm using in a Flutter app. There are light and dark mode versions of each color, and I switch between them using [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). So far, it's working great.

My only issue is my `AppColors` class `require`s all the properties/colors so I don't have to unwrap all the optionals throughout my app.

This means I have to set all the colors in my initializer, but then have a duplicate copy of all those colors to set a `lightColors` variable.

Here's a simplified example of my class definition:

```dart
class AppColors {
  Color alpha;
  Color bravo;

  AppColors({
    required this.alpha,
    required this.bravo,
  });
}
```

And here's my `ThemeNotifier` class:

```dart
class ThemeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  var darkMode = false;

  //Initialize with light mode
  AppColors colors = AppColors(
    alpha: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    bravo: const Color(0xFFF5F5F6),
  );

  //Light mode colors - duplicate of the list above!
  final lightColors = AppColors(
    alpha: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    bravo: const Color(0xFFF5F5F6),
  );

  //Dark mode colors
  final darkColors = AppColors(
    alpha: const Color(0xFF222630),
    bravo: const Color(0xFF171920),
  );

  //Theme Notifier initializer
  ThemeNotifier() {
    Storage.read('darkMode').then((value) {
      darkMode = value ?? false;

      //:::
      colors = darkMode ? darkColors : lightColors;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  void setDarkMode() async {
    colors = darkColors;
    darkMode = true;
    Storage.save('darkMode', true);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setLightMode() async {
    colors = lightColors;
    darkMode = false;
    Storage.save('darkMode', false);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, I have to initialize `AppColors` with **all the required values** or else the Notifier will crash when my app first accesses `colors`.

How can I initialize it without having to have **two copies** of my light colors? As the list of colors gets longer, it gets harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [late](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#lazy-initialization) keyword.

```dart
...
//Initialize with light mode
  late AppColors colors = lightColors;
...
```

You can also set the `colors` as a getter to be based on the `darkMode` and refactor the code like this:

```dart
class ThemeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  var darkMode = false;

  //Initialize with light mode
  AppColors get colors => darkMode ? darkColors : lightColors;

  //Light mode colors - duplicate of the list above!
  final lightColors = AppColors(
    alpha: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    bravo: const Color(0xFFF5F5F6),
  );

  //Dark mode colors
  final darkColors = AppColors(
    alpha: const Color(0xFF222630),
    bravo: const Color(0xFF171920),
  );

  //Theme Notifier initializer
  ThemeNotifier() {
    Storage.read('darkMode').then((value) {
      darkMode = value ?? false;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  void setDarkMode() async {
    darkMode = true;
    Storage.save('darkMode', true);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setLightMode() async {
    darkMode = false;
    Storage.save('darkMode', false);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So will the `late` keyword delay the assignment of `colors` until `lightColors` is set? I'm surprised the compiler doesn't complain that `lightColors` isn't defined when the line `late AppColors colors = lightColors;` is before it is declared. 

Comment: It becomes a lazy initialization. Based on the documentation: `the initializer becomes lazy. Instead of running it as soon as the instance is constructed, it is deferred and run lazily the first time the field is accessed. In other words, it works exactly like an initializer on a top-level variable or static field. This can be handy when the initialization expression is costly and may not be needed.`